# PCLのチュートリアル"Extracting indices from a PointCloud"がビルドできない

Tags: c++, ubuntu, build, cmake

PCLを用いて、点群の中から平面を抽出することを行いたいです。
PCLのチュートリアルの中に "[Extracting indices from a PointCloud](http://vml.sakura.ne.jp/koeda/PCL/tutorials/html/extract_indices.html)" というものがあり、このコードを実行しようとcmakeを用いてビルドしたところ、以下のようなエラーが発生しました。

チュートリアルに記載されているコードをそのままコピペしてビルドしたので、おそらくライブラリ関係でのエラーかと思うのですが、原因がわかりません。どなたか解決策を教えていただけませんでしょうか。

extract_indices.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/ModelCoefficients.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/method_types.h>
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/model_types.h>
#include <pcl/segmentation/sac_segmentation.h>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>
#include <pcl/filters/extract_indices.h>

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::Ptr cloud_blob (new sensor_msgs::PointCloud2), 
  cloud_filtered_blob (new sensor_msgs::PointCloud2);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_filtered (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>), 
  cloud_p (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>), cloud_f (new 
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

  // Fill in the cloud data
  pcl::PCDReader reader;
  reader.read ("table_scene_lms400.pcd", *cloud_blob);

  std::cerr << "PointCloud before filtering: " << cloud_blob->width * cloud_blob->height << 
  " data points." << std::endl;

  // Create the filtering object: downsample the dataset using a leaf size of 1cm
  pcl::VoxelGrid<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> sor;
  sor.setInputCloud (cloud_blob);
  sor.setLeafSize (0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
  sor.filter (*cloud_filtered_blob);

  // Convert to the templated PointCloud
  pcl::fromROSMsg (*cloud_filtered_blob, *cloud_filtered);

  std::cerr << "PointCloud after filtering: " << cloud_filtered->width * cloud_filtered- 
  >height << " data points." << std::endl;

  // Write the downsampled version to disk
  pcl::PCDWriter writer;
  writer.write<pcl::PointXYZ> ("table_scene_lms400_downsampled.pcd", *cloud_filtered, 
  false);

  pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients ());
  pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers (new pcl::PointIndices ());
  // Create the segmentation object
  pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZ> seg;
  // Optional
  seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);
  // Mandatory
  seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
  seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
  seg.setMaxIterations (1000);
  seg.setDistanceThreshold (0.01);

  // Create the filtering object
  pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZ> extract;

  int i = 0, nr_points = (int) cloud_filtered->points.size ();
  // While 30% of the original cloud is still there
  while (cloud_filtered->points.size () > 0.3 * nr_points)
  {
    // Segment the largest planar component from the remaining cloud
    seg.setInputCloud (cloud_filtered);
    seg.segment (*inliers, *coefficients);
    if (inliers->indices.size () == 0)
    {
      std::cerr << "Could not estimate a planar model for the given dataset." << std::endl;
      break;
    }

    // Extract the inliers
    extract.setInputCloud (cloud_filtered);
    extract.setIndices (inliers);
    extract.setNegative (false);
    extract.filter (*cloud_p);
    std::cerr << "PointCloud representing the planar component: " << cloud_p->width * 
    cloud_p->height << " data points." << std::endl;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "table_scene_lms400_plane_" << i << ".pcd";
    writer.write<pcl::PointXYZ> (ss.str (), *cloud_p, false);

    // Create the filtering object
    extract.setNegative (true);
    extract.filter (*cloud_f);
    cloud_filtered.swap (cloud_f);
    i++;
  }

  return (0);
}
```

ビルド結果

```
/home/------/pcl/extract_indices/extract_indices.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/------/pcl/extract_indices/extract_indices.cpp:15:8: error: ‘pcl::PointCloud2’ has not 
been declared
   pcl::PointCloud2::Ptr cloud_blob (new sensor_msgs::PointCloud2), cloud_filtered_blob (new sensor_msgs::PointCloud2);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/------/pcl/extract_indices/extract_indices.cpp:20:43: error: ‘cloud_blob’ was not declared in this scope
   reader.read ("table_scene_lms400.pcd", *cloud_blob);
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/------/pcl/extract_indices/extract_indices.cpp:20:43: note: suggested alternative: ‘cloud_f’
   reader.read ("table_scene_lms400.pcd", *cloud_blob);
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~
                                           cloud_f
/home/------/pcl/extract_indices/extract_indices.cpp:25:18: error: ‘sensor_msgs’ was not declared in this scope
   pcl::VoxelGrid<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> sor;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/------/pcl/extract_indices/extract_indices.cpp:25:42: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   pcl::VoxelGrid<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> sor;
                                          ^
/home/------/pcl/extract_indices/extract_indices.cpp:26:7: error: request for member ‘setInputCloud’ in ‘sor’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   sor.setInputCloud (cloud_blob);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/------/pcl/extract_indices/extract_indices.cpp:27:7: error: request for member ‘setLeafSize’ in ‘sor’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   sor.setLeafSize (0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/------/pcl/extract_indices/extract_indices.cpp:28:7: error: request for member ‘filter’ in ‘sor’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   sor.filter (*cloud_filtered_blob);
       ^~~~~~
/home/------/pcl/extract_indices/extract_indices.cpp:28:16: error: ‘cloud_filtered_blob’ was not declared in this scope
   sor.filter (*cloud_filtered_blob);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/------/pcl/extract_indices/extract_indices.cpp:28:16: note: suggested alternative: ‘cloud_filtered’
   sor.filter (*cloud_filtered_blob);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                cloud_filtered
/home/------/pcl/extract_indices/extract_indices.cpp:31:8: error: ‘fromROSMsg’ is not a member of ‘pcl’
   pcl::fromROSMsg (*cloud_filtered_blob, *cloud_filtered);
        ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/------/pcl/extract_indices/extract_indices.cpp:6:0:
/usr/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/sample_consensus/model_types.h: In function ‘void __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)’:
/usr/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/sample_consensus/model_types.h:99:3: warning: ‘pcl::SAC_SAMPLE_SIZE’ is deprecated: This map is deprecated and is kept only to prevent breaking existing user code. Starting from PCL 1.8.0 model sample size is a protected member of the SampleConsensusModel class [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   SAC_SAMPLE_SIZE (sample_size_pairs, sample_size_pairs + sizeof (sample_size_pairs) / sizeof (SampleSizeModel));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/sample_consensus/model_types.h:99:3: note: declared here
CMakeFiles/extract_indices.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 
'CMakeFiles/extract_indices.dir/extract_indices.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/extract_indices.dir/extract_indices.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/extract_indices.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/extract_indices.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

参考にしたサイトのバージョンが古かったようです。
最新版のチュートリアルを試したところ、無事ビルドできました。